How to write output item when I want to send volume/mute indicator status report from host(windows) to device
This is my current working report descriptor for my custom HID device.
This report descriptor can control host(windows) volume/mute via device.
    0x05, 0x0c,                    // Usage Page (Consumer Devices)       
    0x09, 0x01,                    // Usage (Consumer Control)            
    0xa1, 0x01,                    // Collection (Application)            
        0x15, 0x00,                    //  Logical Minimum (0)                
        0x25, 0x01,                    //  Logical Maximum (1)                
        0x09, 0xe9,                    //  Usage (Volume Up)                  
        0x09, 0xea,                    //  Usage (Volume Down)               
        0x09, 0xe2,                    //  Usage (Mute)
        0x75, 0x01,                    //  Report Size (1)                    
        0x95, 0x03,                    //  Report Count (3)                   
        0x81, 0x02,                    //  Input (Data,Var,Abs)               
        0x75, 0x01,                    //  Report Size (1)                    
        0x95, 0x05,                    //  Report Count (5)                   
        0x81, 0x01,                    //  Input (Cnst,Arr,Abs)               

    0xc0,                          // End Collection                      

My question is if I can add output item to let host(Windows) send Volume Up/Volume down/Mute indicator status to device. Some kind of wrapping volume/Mute usage to visual indicator, and PC will send HID output report to device when I adjust Volume/Mute value on host(windows).
I tried to do this but host(windows) still not sent anything to device.
    0x05, 0x0c,                    // Usage Page (Consumer Devices)       
    0x09, 0x01,                    // Usage (Consumer Control)            
    0xa1, 0x01,                    // Collection (Application)            
        0x15, 0x00,                    //  Logical Minimum (0)                
        0x25, 0x01,                    //  Logical Maximum (1)                
        0x09, 0xe9,                    //  Usage (Volume Up)                  
        0x09, 0xea,                    //  Usage (Volume Down)                
        0x09, 0xe2,                    //  Usage (Mute)
        0x75, 0x01,                    //  Report Size (1)                    
        0x95, 0x03,                    //  Report Count (3)                   
        0x81, 0x02,                    //  Input (Data,Var,Abs)               
        0x75, 0x01,                    //  Report Size (1)                    
        0x95, 0x05,                    //  Report Count (5)                   
        0x81, 0x01,                    //  Input (Cnst,Arr,Abs)               
        
        0x05, 0x08,                    //  USAGE_PAGE (LEDs)
        0x09, 0x3a,                    //  USAGE (Usage Selected Indicator)
        0xa1, 0x02,                    //  COLLECTION (Logical)
            0x05, 0x0c,                    // Usage Page (Consumer Devices)       
            0x09, 0x01,                    // Usage (Consumer Control)            
            0xa1, 0x01,                    // Collection (Application)            
                0x15, 0x00,                    //  Logical Minimum (0)                
                0x25, 0x01,                    //  Logical Maximum (1)                
                0x09, 0xe9,                    //  Usage (Volume Up)                  
                0x09, 0xea,                    //  Usage (Volume Down)                
                0x09, 0xe2,                    //  Usage (Mute)
                0x75, 0x01,                    //  Report Size (1)                    
                0x95, 0x03,                    //  Report Count (3)                   
                0x91, 0x02,                    //  OUTPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
                0x75, 0x01,                    //  Report Size (1)                    
                0x95, 0x05,                    //  Report Count (5)                   
                0x91, 0x03,                    //  OUTPUT (Cnst,Var,Abs)
            0xc0,                          // End Collection                      
        0xc0,                           //  END_COLLECTION
    0xc0,                          // End Collection     

Anyone can help with this issue?
